# Что такое Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Объясните понятным языком, что это такое?

Пишу первую верстку сайта и задумался над его адаптивностью на экранах с разными разрешениями + еще нужно добавить слайдер. Почитал и понял, что нужно использовать Bootstrap, но не могу понять его функцию и как мне решить все вышеперечисленные вопросы.

Что делать с макетом? Заново всё переписывать, что ли?
И где лучше всего изучать Bootstrap?

Comment: Можете начать с прочтения описания [метки bootstrap](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/bootstrap/info)

Comment: Слишком много вопросов!

Comment: Адаптивность можно делать и без bootstrap

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546709/

Comment: 1) если вы занимаетесь практикой по html, css - делайте без Bootstrap, 2) переписывать необязательно, можно использовать медиа запросы

Answer (score 9):

Рекомендую учебный раздел [на Webreference.ru](https://webref.ru/layout/bootstrap). Там изложены базовые понятия Бутстрапа, а  рядом — справочники [по CSS](https://webref.ru/css) и [HTML](https://webref.ru/html).

Бутстрап — конструктор с набором готовых решений. На нём можно собрать адаптивный сайт со слайдером и всем прочим, но за один подход Бутстрап не освоить.

Зато можно подключать Бутстрап, но использовать его только там, где нужно.

Поэтому предлагаю продвигаться небольшими шагами. Выберите одну локальную задачу и решите её с помощью Бутстрапа. Например, добавьте слайдер из Бутстрапа или перепишите на Бутстрапе один из блоков на своём сайте.

Посмотрите как устроены [базовые примеры](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples-framework). HTML-коды для слайдера и других модулей приведены [в документации по ним](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel).

Сделайте себе заготовку HTML-страницы, которая подключает Джиквери и Бутстрап с CDN, чтобы было легче тренероваться и проверять чужие решения. Например:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
  <header></header>
  <footer></footer>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Практиковаться удобно на https://codepen.io/ Там стили и скрипты Бутстрапа можно подключать из выпадающего меню.

Попробовав каждый модуль, разберетесь, что Бутстрап умеет сам, а что нет. Тогда смотрите на русском и английском SO, как решают подобные вопросы. Для некоторых ситуаций есть стандартные доработки, а для других лучше использовать не Бутстрап.

Answer (score 3):

[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_(%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA)):

> Это свободный набор инструментов для создания сайтов и веб-приложений. Включает в себя HTML- и CSS-шаблоны оформления для типографики, веб-форм, кнопок, меток, блоков навигации и прочих компонентов веб-интерфейса, включая JavaScript-расширения.
>
> Bootstrap использует современные наработки в области CSS и HTML, поэтому необходимо быть внимательным при поддержке старых браузеров.

Вот Вам как вариант документация на русском языке http://bootstrap-3.ru/index.php

Answer (score 2):

Настраиваемый HTML, CSS и Javascript [фреймворк](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA) для более быстрой и удобной Web-разработки.
Начать его изучать вы можете по урокам [здесь](https://tokar.ua/read/6901).

Answer (score 1):

В bootstrap используется как я называю классовая верстка т.е. `.class`.

С помощью этого фреймворка можно создавать [адаптивные](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD) сайты.

Скачать четвертую версию можно с [этого сайта](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) а третью [здесь](http://getbootstrap.com/).

А насчет макета скорее всего заново. Вот несколько документаций http://bootstrap-3.ru/  http://bootstrap-ru.com/ http://mybootstrap.ru/